# How to pass an array from the controller to the view Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a consult, I need to pass the data of an array in the controller to the view, but when I get the data from the array in the view it gives me an error.

```
"Illegal string offset 'name'
```

Controller

```
for($i=0; $i < count($num); $i++) {

    $data = [ 
        'name' => $input['name'][$i],
        'price' => $input['price'][$i],
        'quantity' => intval($input['quantity'][$i]),
        'created_at'=>$now, 
        'updated_at'=>$now,
    ];
}
return view('view', compact('data'));
```

View

```
 @foreach($data as $dat)
    <tr>
        <td width="100">Product</td>
        <td width="50">Quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $dat['name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $dat['quantity'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

dd($data)

```
array:5 [▼
  "name" => "name1"
  "price" => "14.00"
  "quantity" => 1
  "created_at" => "2018-12-11 09:03:35"
  "updated_at" => "2018-12-11 09:03:35"
]
```

What am I wrong about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but try this

```
$data = [];

for($i=0; $i < count($num); $i++) {

$temp = [ 
    'name' => $input['name'][$i],
    'price' => $input['price'][$i],
    'quantity' => intval($input['quantity'][$i]),
    'created_at'=>$now, 
    'updated_at'=>$now,
];
array_push($data,$temp);
}
return view('view', compact('data'));
```

Comment: It worked!! I do not know how, but now it works correctly, thank you very much

Comment: With your code you are getting ```Array ( [name] => test [price] => 5000 [quantity] => 10 [created_at] => 1995 [updated_at] => 1995 )``` and with new code your are getting ```Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => test [price] => 5000 [quantity] => 10 [created_at] => 1995 [updated_at] => 1995 ) )```.  That why your ```for loop``` was running on individual elements ```name```, ```price``` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing right, problem is in your array. It isn't multidimensional, but you are trying to access it like multidimensional.

```
$data = [];

for($i=0; $i < count($num); $i++) {
    $data[] = [ 
        'name' => $input['name'][$i],
        'price' => $input['price'][$i],
        'quantity' => intval($input['quantity'][$i])
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem continues, the error is the same :(

Comment: What the result of `dd($data);`?

Comment: I added the complete data

Comment: Are you sure, you tried my code? Did you clean cache after that? Your problem is that you have a simple array of strings, but you need array of arrays (multidimensional).

Comment: Yes, I have tested your code but the error is the same. I did a lot of tests and when I use      {{ $ data ['name'] }} if it gives me the result, the problem is when it's inside the foreach

Comment: Now the error is Undefined offset: 1. I think it's because the foreach is in a loop of 5 times and I only get 2 data from the array

Comment: Try ```$dat``` in instead of ```$dat['name']```

Comment: Now there are no errors and you get the entire array in its last position

Comment: I guess for your ```for loop``` is running in your ```$data``` each element. That` why ```$dat['var']``` is not showing anything.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it